# Solve matrix equation $AX = (1/2)(X)$, where $A$ is $5\times5$ and $a_{ij} = \pm 1$

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations

*Let $A$ be a $5\times5$ matrix, such that any element $a_{ij}$ equals either 1 or -1. Find all solutions of the equation:
$$AX = \frac{1}{2}X$$
where $X \in \mathbb{R}^5$.*

What I've tried:

If $X$ is some solution, then $X' =(\alpha X - \beta X)$ is also a solution ($\alpha , \beta \in \mathbb{R}$).

This means, that we can get such solution $X$ (if any exists at all), that $x_1 = 1$. This simplifies a bit our system of linear equations:

$$\begin{cases} \pm 1 \pm x_2 ... \pm x_5 = \frac{1}{2} \\ ... \\ \pm 1 \pm x_2 + ... + \pm x_5 = \frac{1}{2}x_5 \end{cases}$$

Here I tried to solve this system, but got a mess of "$\pm$" signs and think that this is not the way this task should be solved.

Comment: It means in particular that 1/2 is an eigenvalue...

Comment: I have tried an extended simulation: I have found no solution (the closest eigenvalue is 0.501...). Do you know if this is the objective ?

Comment: I do not have any additional info besides the task itself (I took it from some old entrance exam on MS program), but I assume that it can have such a "trick" with no solutions at all

Comment: @JeanMarie If there are no matrices eigenvalue = 1/2, that means X = 0 is the unique solution ;)

Comment: That's right...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The characteristic polynomial is of the form
$$t^5-a_1 t^4 + a_2 t^3 - a_3 t^2 +a_4 t -a_5,$$
where the $a_j$ are integers. 
Suppose $\frac{1}{2}$ is a characteristic root. 
Then substitute in, multiply by 32 and --- 1 is even!

So we see that the only possible $X$ is $0$.